# How to click on element inside shadowroot using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webautomation

I am using a captcha bypass extension called "Buster: Captcha Solver for Humans
1.3.1". Works great but cant seem to click on its button for this website because its blocked by a shadowroot. I have no experience in bypassing shadowroots so please any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I have been working for this on hours and still have no luck. Below is a snippet of the code I am making for this site. The site is https://www.biblegateway.com/newsletters/ and the captcha in the shadow root appears when you enter a email and click on subscribe. I posted pics to help describe this problem as well!

```
from lib2to3.pgen2 import driver
import random
import string
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome import options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from time import sleep, time_ns
import pynput
import threading
from threading import Thread
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options1 = Options()
chrome_options1.add_extension(r'D:\mpbjkejclgfgadiemmefgebjfooflfhl.crx')
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path= PATH, options=chrome_options1)
driver1.get("https://www.biblegateway.com/newsletters/")
driver1.maximize_window()


email_box = driver1.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/section/div[3]/section/form/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/input')
email_box.click()
email_box.send_keys('testingthecaptcha@gmail.com')
time.sleep(2)

clicky = driver1.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/section/div[3]/section/form/div/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/label[1]/input')
clicky.click()
time.sleep(3)

clicky1 = driver1.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div/section/div[3]/section/form/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/input')
clicky1.click()
print('done')
time.sleep(2)

#Below is where I just could not click the element or bypass the shadowroot!!!!!!!
captcha_solver = driver1.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@placeholder='Instrument']")
captcha_solver.click()
time.sleep(3)
print('done')
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using selenium 4:

```
shadow_root = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, 'shadow-root-parent-element').shadow_root
element_in_shadow_root = shadow_root.find_element(By.XPATH, 'element-in-shadow-root')
```

e.g.

```
shadow_root = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'game-app').shadow_root
game = shadow_root.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#game')
```

[image: page-source-example]