# Set shadow root mode to "open" with selenium

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, shadow-dom

I'm doing automation with selenium in python. At some point in my code, I have to access and click a button. This button is inside a shadow root whose mode is "closed", itself inside an iframe. (I'm trying to bypass google's ReCaptcha using [this addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/buster-captcha-solver/), [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70947416/how-to-click-on-element-inside-shadowroot-using-selenium) about the subject could not help me because the response assumes the shadow root is open which is not the case). I have found [an article](https://blog.revillweb.com/open-vs-closed-shadow-dom-9f3d7427d1af) explaining how does it work and how to bypass it, the best solution is given at the end of the article :

> There is nothing stopping someone executing the following JavaScript before your component definition
>
> ```js
> Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
> Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
>    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
> };
> ```

This seems to override the `attachShadow` method to force every future shadow roots to be open.
Doing so will solve my problem, because I would be able to call `myComponent.shadowRoot`.
My problem is that I can't do something like :

```py
driver.get(link)
driver.execute_script("""
       Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
       Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
           return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
       };
""")
```

Because the captcha's iframe won't be affected by this, only the main content will be affeted. So I concluded I have to swith to the iframe before executing the script.

This is what I tried :
The captcha only generates after I click on a certain button.
Let's say I do something like this :

```py
driver.get(link)
button = driver.find_element(...)
button.click()
iframe = driver.find_element(...)
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.execute_script("""
      Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
      Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
          return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
      };

""")
```

In that case, I can successfully switch to the desired frame, but by doing this, the content of the iframe was generated **before** the execution of the script and therefore the shadow root is still closed. I've also looked for github repos or other articles but they seem all out of date ([this repo](https://github.com/teal33t/captcha_bypass) mentionned in [this article](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/how-to-easily-bypass-recaptchav2-with-selenium-7f7a9a44fa9e)) for instance.

I also tried opening the browser's console, selecting the desired element and just like mentionned in the article, looking for a `_root` element or something similar that might contain the shadow root. I'm far from a javascript professionnal, but the article mentions :

> Of course you could take it one step further and wrap the Custom Element definition in a closure to prevent the reference to the Shadow Root from being accessible

This prevent accessing the shadow root using `_root` or similar, so I suppose that it is what have been used. The script given at the end seems to be the only workaround.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75387864/how-to-click-on-an-element-within-shadow-rootclosed) seems to address my issue by using chrome's `Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument`, but does not solve it:
The code

```py
driver.execute_cdp_cmd('Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument', {'source': """
Element.prototype._attachShadow = Element.prototype.attachShadow;
Element.prototype.attachShadow = function () {
    return this._attachShadow( { mode: "open" } );
};
"""})
```

Will effectively load the script before the page has loaded, but this will not affect the iframes inside the page.

Comment: In every business we test the component before it is used. We never test the wheel after we bought the car. Don't test the wheel!

Comment: What a vague message, I hope I'll get some actual concrete advice in the future to help me with this problem !